# Cordova Android - ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command:

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I've just had a Cordova project land on my lap and i've been tasked with building the apps and getting them on the stores. iOS worked fine but now i've hit a wall with Android.

So, every time i build - by running cordova build android - im getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sprince/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.432 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /Users/sprince/Documents/Projects/ProjName/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/sprince/Documents/Projects/ProjName/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/sprince/Documents/Projects/ProjName/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/sprince/Documents/Projects/ProjName/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I've been googling around and had a good search through Stack and most responses are saying do a clean and rebuild. I've done this a few times now and had no luck, I've checked and i have all the SDKs / tools etc installed.

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you used android sdk manager to install android sdk platform 23 ?

Comment: Yes, they have been installed.

Comment: you can try to run `cordova build android --stacktrace` to see if you have more details about the error. Or you can also try to run `platforms/android/cordova/check_reqs` to check if cordova finds all the requirements. Are you building in OSX?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: building on OS X, same problem ! @QuickFix

Comment: I'm having the same issue. By checking your error, I would suggest you to delete and install again the android libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I deleted the 1.5 GB libraries android installs when creating devices. After some weeks I just tried to run on android with same error message. Just open avd and remove all devices, reinstall the devices you need to test.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html